# iOS Simulator gets stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am using Xcode 9.1, but the following issue happened with Xcode 9 as well.

Sometimes, after running an application in the simulator and stopping the execution from Xcode, the simulator gets stuck in a loop and **opens/closes the same application rapidly and endlessly**.

The fix that I know for this issue is running an application from Xcode again or quitting the simulator.

It seems like the OS of the simulator is not a key factor, it already happened with multiple different simulators.

If I try to close the application by pressing the Home button, SpringBoard throws a crash:

[image: SpringBoard's crash window]

Here is a relevant snippet from the crash:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'need the old view controller for <SBLayoutElement: 0x600001a7f3c0; identifier: [application's ID]; layoutRole: primary; layoutElementMode: default> {
    supportedLayoutRoles = primary;
    layoutAttributes = none;
    viewControllerClass = SBMainWorkspaceApplicationSceneLayoutElementViewController;
}'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
CoreSimulator 494.22.7 - Device: iPhone 6 - Runtime: iOS 11.1 (15B87) - DeviceType: iPhone 6

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115bc61ab __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011525bf41 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115bcb372 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
3   Foundation                          0x0000000111085089 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
4   SpringBoard                         0x0000000108e5f17a SpringBoard + 2863482
5   SpringBoard                         0x00000001090980bc SpringBoard + 5193916
6   SpringBoard                         0x0000000108e5e9c9 SpringBoard + 2861513
7   SpringBoard                         0x00000001090be78d SpringBoard + 5351309
8   SpringBoard                         0x0000000108e60902 SpringBoard + 2869506
9   SpringBoard                         0x0000000108e17094 SpringBoard + 2568340
10  SpringBoard                         0x0000000108f5d197 SpringBoard + 3903895
11  SpringBoard                         0x0000000108f5d253 SpringBoard + 3904083
12  SpringBoard                         0x0000000108f5d86b SpringBoard + 3905643
13  SpringBoard                         0x0000000108f5c4a0 SpringBoard + 3900576
14  SpringBoard                         0x0000000108f5aea9 SpringBoard + 3894953
15  BaseBoard                           0x000000010e749091 __22-[BSTransaction begin]_block_invoke + 178
16  BaseBoard                           0x000000010e74f7b7 -[BSTransaction _preventTransactionCompletionForReason:ignoringAuditHistory:andExecuteBlock:] + 66
17  BaseBoard                           0x000000010e748c4b -[BSTransaction begin] + 890
18  BaseBoard                           0x000000010e749136 __22-[BSTransaction begin]_block_invoke + 343
19  BaseBoard                           0x000000010e74f7b7 -[BSTransaction _preventTransactionCompletionForReason:ignoringAuditHistory:andExecuteBlock:] + 66
20  BaseBoard                           0x000000010e748c4b -[BSTransaction begin] + 890
21  SpringBoard                         0x0000000108beea28 SpringBoard + 305704
22  SpringBoard                         0x0000000108bf1875 SpringBoard + 317557
23  SpringBoard                         0x0000000108bf1597 SpringBoard + 316823
24  SpringBoard                         0x0000000108befee4 SpringBoard + 311012
25  BaseBoard                           0x000000010e7569c8 -[BSEventQueue _processNextEvent] + 349
26  SpringBoard                         0x0000000108beeb3b SpringBoard + 305979
27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000116dd8273 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000116dd92b5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
29  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000116de3496 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1260
30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115b88ee9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115b4d592 __CFRunLoopRun + 2402
32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115b4c9b9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
33  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001115e89c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
34  UIKit                               0x000000010c0fb5e8 UIApplicationMain + 159
35  FrontBoard                          0x000000010e4efdfa FBSystemAppMain + 1010
36  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000116e4dd81 start + 1
37  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

Is there a known fix for this?

Comment: Can you file a bug on this with the output of `xcrun simctl diagnose` after it happens (while the Simulator is still running)?

Comment: @russbishop I filed a bug.

Comment: Can you tell me the radar #?

Comment: @russbishop The ID is 35748153.

Comment: Ah I didn't recognize this one at first; various 3rd party kernel extensions are known to cause problems like this. Please try disabling any 3rd party firewalls, virus scanners, etc temporarily then try again. If it still happens let us know.